# Can the Xbox Live Creators Program grant access to the XBL RESTful API for web development?

Tags: xbox, xbox-live

I'm developing a website that requires access to public profile and game information from Xbox Live, for that I need authorization to use the Xbox Live RESTful API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/api-ref/xbox-live-rest/atoc-xboxlivews-reference)

Apparently the way to get that is with the Xbox Live Creators Program (https://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/creators-program/)

Researching online is giving me conflicting reports about whether this can be used for developing a website rather than an Xbox game or UWP app.
I'd rather be sure before paying the membership fee for a Microsoft developer account.

So can you use the API for a website by joining the Xbox Live Creators Program?