# Xbox Creators Program and REST API

Tags: rest, xbox, xbox-live

I recently applied for the Xbox Creators program to get access to their REST API. However, their documentation doesn't seem to mention how to authenticate using REST API. The documentation talks about XSAPI wrapper. I assume it comes with Xbox game development kit. I couldn't find its source code online.

I don't want to create a video game. I just want to create a web app and call the Xbox API using Python or JavaScript. If anyone is familiar with this process please point me to the right direction.

I found a question similar to mine but is was unanswered.

[Can the Xbox Live Creators Program grant access to the XBL RESTful API for web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207241/can-the-xbox-live-creators-program-grant-access-to-the-xbl-restful-api-for-web-d)

Documentation Link: [Xbox services overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/live/get-started/live-xbl-overview)

I am hoping by now someone has at least figured something out.

Side note:

I am familar with OpenXBL, XAPI, and other similar services. I want to check if I can do it using official API before buying a monthly subscription of their service.